# getting the file size before downloading in android

Tags: android

Can anybody tell me how to get the size of a file before downloading it from server(may be http,ftp or anything) in android?.Does streaming works?. Please Help me..

Regards
Varnesh

Answer (score 5):

Try this will work in case the http server is giving the file size

```
URL myUrl = new URL("http://jamants.com/file.mp3");
URLConnection urlConnection = myUrl.openConnection(); 
urlConnection.connect();
int file_size = urlConnection.getContentLength();
```

Or second Version try this.

```
URL myUrl = new URL("http://jamants.com/file.mp3");
myConnection = myUrl.openConnection();
List headersize = myConnection.getHeaderFields().get("content-Lenght");
```

It Works in my project.

Comment: Man, the second version saved my day, I had to add file size manually in mysql database, now no need to

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the built-in Apahce HTTP library to make a request for a file, you can get the file size by requesting the headers only.  Inside the headers will be a "content-length" attribute that will indicate the number of bytes of the requested file.  Requesting the headers will not request the file itself.