# How to get the size of the video in Kilobytes?

Tags: android, video

Is it possible to get the size of the video in kilobytes in android? Is there any API for that?

> Update
>   I am trying to fetch the video from a http:// location.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
File file = new File("xxx.flv");

long length = file.length();

length = length/1024;
```

Comment: What if i am trying to get a video file from the http://. Is it possible to get the size by reading the metadata?

Comment: You ought to mention such things in the question. Read about [range requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411480/how-to-resume-an-interrupted-download/3411558#3411558). or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276249/getting-the-file-size-before-downloading-in-android/3276263#3276263)